# How to check if a point/address lies on a route?

Tags: google-maps

If I have a set of routes between various locations, and I have the lat/long co-ordinates for a point on the map, is it possible to find out if the point lies on any of the routes in my set? Basically if i get a GPS fix on a location, I want to find out if that location lies on any of my pre-determined routes.

Answer (score 2):

This can be a complex computation. You should do this gradually and just check it roughly first. E.g. for every route, keep track of max-lat, max-long, min-lat and min-long. Then you can do a quick check if the point is within the max-min square. If that check is true - your point may be on your route, and you need to do more checks.